# Why does counter keep getting reset?

Tags: ruby

I've created a simple game where the user has to alphabetize the order of a word to score. For some odd reason score is returning 1 even though the user gets 2 questions correct. What am I doing wrong?

```
def alphabetize(word)
    word.chars.sort_by(&:downcase).join
end

def words
    %w(hello yes)
end

@correct = 0
@incorrect = 0

def score
    (@correct / @correct + @incorrect)
end

words.each do |word|
    puts "Alphabetize '#{word}'"
    answer = gets.chomp
    if answer == alphabetize(word)
        @correct += 1
        p 'Nice!'
    else
        @incorrect += 1
        p 'You suck!'
    end
end

p "Your score: #{score}"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because:

```
@correct / @correct
```

will always be 1

Comment: Silly me! I misplaced the parentheses.

Comment: Watch out for integer division.  1/2 = 0